# Magento 2: Browser console error on hard refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento-2.2.5, magento-upgrade

I am facing some weird issue with Magento 2.2.5 version. When I first-time open website, I am getting lots of js errors. (Screenshot attached)

After this, when I only press F5 button (normal refresh) then the errors are gone. Again I pressed Control+F5 (Hard refresh), facing the same errors in console.

I have tried clearing cache, static content deploy, merging JS/CSS, 777 folder permission on var/* and pub/* but no luck.

Can anyone help me with this? [image]

Comment: are you using porto theme ?

Comment: No we are using custom theme.

Comment: Check answers & give feedback

Answer (score 0):

**Magento2** files & folders permissions are not intended to be such simple to work as it was Magento1, for instance. That 777 try is not a good idea

I'd take a look first at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Once you are sure that your working environment is correctly configured to host a Magento2 website, I'd repeat this command sequence (if you are working in **production mode**, if you are not then you can omit the static content deploy part)

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

That commands should generate all content the application needs to work & you can then assume that JS errors are not related to permissions